# Rotated Rectangles

Tags: graphics, generative-art

I would like to produce an image similar to the upper half of this graphics by Victor Vasarely.

[image]

All I could produce so far is this dilettante image:

```
g = Graphics[{GrayLevel@0.7, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 30];
h = Graphics[{GrayLevel@0.7, Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/12]}, ImageSize -> 30];

Grid[{
  {g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, g, g, h, g, g, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, g, h, h, h, g, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, h, h, h, h, h, g, g, g},
  {g, g, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, g, g},
  {g, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, g},
  {g, g, h, h, h, h, h, h, h, g, g},
  {g, g, g, h, h, h, h, h, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, g, h, h, h, g, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, g, g, h, g, g, g, g, g},
  {g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g, g}},
 Background -> GrayLevel@0.2,
 Spacings -> {0.1, 0}]
```

[image]

I also tried scaled rectangles and parallelograms but to no avail: The forms don't align "properly"(equal vertical spacings).

Maybe `Grid` is an inept tool to get the desired effect?

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: (at) eldo: Honestly speaking, in the graphics of Victor Vaserely I don't see rotated rectangles, not even rhombus but "at most" paralelograms with angles progressing according to a more or less complicated rule as we move along. So, if you really want to reproduce Vasarely's graphics we need to agree on the deformation rule. (BTW, I like your graph :-)

Comment: (at) eldo: look at that: h = Graphics[{GrayLevel@0.7, Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/12]}, ImageSize -> 40]; gives a beautiful displacements of the outer squares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first attempt, using `ShearingTransform`

```
sd[i_, j_] := 
 If[And[4 <= j <= 10, 8 - j <= i - 1 <= j, 
   j - 6 <= i - 1 <= 14 - j], -20, 0]
GraphicsGrid[
 Table[
  Graphics[{GrayLevel@0.7,
    GeometricTransformation[
     GeometricTransformation[
      Rectangle[],
      ShearingTransform[sd[i, j] Degree, {0, 1}, {1, 0}]],
     RescalingTransform[{{-1, 1}, 
       If[sd[i, j] == 0, {0, 1}, {0, 1.5}]}, {{-1, 1}, {0, 
        1}}]]}], {i, 9}, {j, 12}], Background -> GrayLevel@0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I think this meets the *equal vertical spacings* criterion but assumes that each of the parallelograms are sheared by the same amount, which does not appear to be correct.

Comment: 1000 thanks for your answer. It is much nearer to what I want :)

Answer (score 7):

Your Vasarely graphic reminds me of an old Mathematica Jounal [article](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v7i3/edpick/html/Links/index_lnk_2.html) by Flip Phillips about the work of William [Kolomyjec](http://atariarchives.org/artist/sec15.php). It's not the same effect, but may provide some amusement. The distance function d may be the following, or Norm or ChessboardDistance or ... Other parameters include scalings of colours, rotation angles, and translations.

```
Block[{hmax = 34, vmax = 21, d},
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}],
      Table[
         d = Min[i, j, hmax - i - 1, vmax - j - 1]/Max[hmax, vmax];
         {ColorData["FallColors", 2.2 d^0.7],
          Translate[
             Rotate[Rectangle[{i, j}], 2 d*RandomReal[{0, 1}]*\[Pi]/2],
             400 E^(-6 (1 - d)) RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 2]]},
         {i, 0, hmax - 1}, {j, 0, vmax - 1}]},
      Background -> Black]]
```

[image: Kolomyjec]

Comment: Thanks @ Kenny very beautyful and fun to play with :)

Comment: A work of art !

Answer (score 5):

First, create a matrix for shape positions:

```
a = ArrayPad[
  ArrayPad[DiamondMatrix[2], 1] + DiamondMatrix[3], {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}]
```

Then, apply geometric transformations to appropriate positions.

```
Graphics[{LightGray, MapIndexed[Which[
     #1 == 0, Scale[Rectangle[#2, #2 + 1], .8],
     #1 == 2, 
     GeometricTransformation[
      Translate[Scale[Rectangle[#2, #2 + 1], {.8, .85}], {0, .2}], 
      ShearingTransform[-20 Degree, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, #2]],
     #1 == 1, 
     Which[a[[Sequence @@ (Reverse[#2] + {1, 0})]] == 0 \[And] 
       a[[Sequence @@ (Reverse[#2] - {1, 0})]] == 0, 
      GeometricTransformation[
       Translate[Scale[Rectangle[#2, #2 + 1], {.8, .7}], {0, .2}], 
       ShearingTransform[-20 Degree, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, #2]],
      a[[Sequence @@ (Reverse[#2] + {1, 0})]] == 0, 
      GeometricTransformation[
       Translate[Scale[Rectangle[#2, #2 + 1], {.8, .8}], {0, .15}], 
       ShearingTransform[-20 Degree, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, #2]],
      True, 
      GeometricTransformation[
       Translate[Scale[Rectangle[#2, #2 + 1], {.8, .8}], {0, .25}], 
       ShearingTransform[-20 Degree, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, #2]]]
     ] &, Transpose[a], {2}]}, Background -> Darker[Gray, .7], 
 PlotRangePadding -> .15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are five different groups of shapes:

- the rectangles outside the diamond that are only scaled
- the rectangles inside the diamond are scaled and sheared in four different ways:

  - the left and right corner,
  - the top edge,
  - the bottom edge and
  - the inside of the diamond.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what is asked but it may be a good start too.

Alternative approach with `Grid`:

```
opt = {ImageSize -> {20, 20}, BaseStyle -> GrayLevel@.9};

Composition[
  Framed[Grid[#, Spacings -> {.3, .3}], Background -> Black] &,

  ArrayPad[#, {2, 2}, Graphics[Rectangle[], opt]] &,

  # + (DiamondMatrix[5] /. {1 -> 0, 0 -> 1}) Graphics[Rectangle[], opt] &
  ][
     DiamondMatrix[5] Graphics[ Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, -.4}, {1, .6}, {0, 1}}], opt]
   ]
```

[image]